# Answerer Name comment highlighter

Tags: script, comments, display-name

### Update: This has been added to my [Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) - please go there for the latest version.

---

After reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/highlight-comments-from-answer-author-in-addition-to-question-author), I really liked the idea, so I made a Userscript to highlight answerer's names.

The [script](https://gist.github.com/shu8/0e129717497ba192f0d8):

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Highlight answerer's comments
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%B9%A7%D0%BD%CA%8A%C3%9F
// @version      0.2
// @description  Highlight's the names of answerer's on SE websites
// @author       ṧнʊß (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%B9%A7%D0%BD%CA%8A%C3%9F)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function colorAnswerer() {
    $('.answercell').each(function(x, obj) {
        var x = $(this).find('.user-details a').text();
        $('.answer .comment-user').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).text() == x) { 
                $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }
        });        
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comments').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted' || event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
            colorAnswerer();
        }
    });
});
```

It might be buggy - I've only tested it on Chrome on a few questions across the network. Please post bug reports! :)

[image]

### Change Log

- 06/01/15 - v0.2: Fixed bug where CSS was removed after clicking `show x more comments`.
- 15/01/15 - v0.3: Fixed deprecation of v0.2 (DOMNodeInserted)

<sub>(NORMAL dates, not American ones ;p)</sub>

Comment: Try testing it on [posts like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277228/331508) that have hidden comments. (I haven't done this, just sayin'.)

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for that - I've fixed it and updated the post :)