# Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)

Tags: script, tampermonkey

[image: Join the chat at https://gitter.im/soscripted/sox]

#### SOX v2.8.0

Stack Overflow Extras (*SOX*) is a project that stemmed from the [Stack Overflow Optional Features (SOOF)](https://github.com/shu8/Stack-Overflow-Optional-Features) project.

The SOX userscript adds a bunch of **optional** features to all sites in the Stack Exchange network. These can be toggled on or off from an easy to use control panel (see screenshot below).

Note: This project has no relation to Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange; it is simply a userscript that enhances the sites!

### Installation & Requirements

1. Install [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/). This is a userscript manager that *must* be installed in order for this to work, as the script relies on certain `GM_*` functions in order to save your settings!
2. Install the script. Clicking on 'install' below will make your userscript manager prompt you automatically to install it.

   - Official Version: <kbd>[install](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/v2.8.0/sox.user.js)</kbd>. <kbd>[view source](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/blob/v2.8.0/sox.user.js)</kbd>
   - Development Version: <kbd>[install](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js)</kbd>. <kbd>[view source](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/blob/dev/sox.user.js)</kbd>
3. Go to any site in the Stack Exchange Network (e.g. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)). You will automatically be asked to choose and save your settings. A toggle button (gears icon) will be added to your topbar where you can change these later on:

[image: newdialog]

### What features are included?

A full list of all the features is available on the SOX wiki page [here](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Features).

### Bugs and Feature Requests

Please post bugs and feature requests as issues on [Github](https://github.com/soscripted/sox), where we can track them easily and push updates quickly. Please **do not** post them as answers on Stack Apps -- they are much harder to manage!

### Contribute

Pull requests to add new features or improve the existing ones, etc. are welcome! Please head to the [Contributing](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Contributing) wiki page to get started.

### Changes

Please see the change log [at Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/a/6358).

Comment: If you use `GM setValue()` instead of a cookie, then your script will remember the options across every site.  They could even be synched from one machine to another, if the user desires.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks - added that in the latest version :)

Comment: Here's one feature you might consider: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249679/putting-the-edit-box-and-the-markdown-box-side-by-side (There's no way that would get into SOUP, but as an optional feature...)

Comment: Can you add solid bg to "Make the vote buttons sticky" feature? It'd also (at least for me) be nice if the question width would remain unaltered.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski There's still a bug in the sticky button feature which I need to fix (sometime..), but if you could add this as an issue with label 'enhancement', I can look at it when I fix the other bug. Thanks! :) (and sorry for the extremely late reply -- I missed the notification!)

Comment: For anyone who uses Safari, as a replacement for Greasemonkey, etc., you can use NinjaKit.

Comment: @BrockAdams I was just testing whether the settings that I set via GM_setValue were being synced and it doesn't seem they are. I'm using Tampermonkey and Chrome with TESLA enabled. Is there a hidden setting anywhere to sync settings as well as scripts?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, Sync is primarily Firefox.  I haven't investigated Chrome sync in a long while (it's not my primary browser) and Chrome changed extension storage a bit ago.  You did sign into Chrome and set the Advanced sync settings, right?  If so, then hit up the Tampermonkey forum for more.  Chrome can sync extension data, but the developer has to code for that.

Comment: @BrockAdams yeah, everything is checked to be synced. Thanks for your help though! I'm going to check and ask on the TM forum now. So does it sync gm_setValue settings in FF?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, it did in Firefox once upon a time.  Haven't rechecked in a while but it still should.

Comment: Wow, so many features. I was astonished when clicked that button in the top bar :D

Comment: Have you added the inline editor btw?

Comment: @nicael :D there are loads!!! sorry, not yet, been really busy these past few days. Might not be till next weekend :/

Comment: Is there a way to hide the settings cog at the top?  Once I have configured my settings, I don't always want it shown there...

Comment: @iRove sorry, not really; if the cogs icon got hidden then there would be no way to ever get back to the settings panel again if you ever wanted to disable a feature, or more importantly *enable* a new feature that comes in new versions. If you really dislike it, if you have an ad-blocker, you can 'block' the element and unblock it in the future...? If you have any other ideas, I'd be happy to look into them, but there needs to be a way to open the settings panel again :/

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Thank you for the quick response!  Wow, clever.  I'll try to use my ad-blocker to enable/disable the settings cog and get back to you in a second.  Love the features in the script!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Your solution with the ad-blocker worked perfectly.  Just blocked the element on all stack exchange sites, and can unblock it whenever I want to customize.  I appreciate the time and effort you put into this project! :-)

Comment: What's are the differences between the "Official" and "Development" versions? Would I install both of them, or choose one? If I choose one, how do I remove it to choose the other if I change my mind later?

Comment: @Kevin the official version is the version most people would choose: it's the version we release every few months that is stable and working. The development version is the one with new features being developed and bugs being fixed but it isn't stable and might break now and again. You only need to install one of them. If you choose one you can go into tampermonkey or grease monkey and delete SOX and install the other version :)

Comment: Is there any way to save/export your settings? I've tweaked this just the way I like it, and it would be nice to have that available on multiple machines.

Comment: @Cody there isn't currently, but I've planned a feature where you can do this but we've both been really busy these past few months and haven't gotten round to doing it :(( if you have chrome or Firefox there's a "sync" option in it so it syncs across computers logged into the same account - you could try that until we manage to get this working? :) Sorry it's not there yet :/ I hope you're finding it useful though! :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just installed it a couple of days ago. Had to come here to figure out I needed the development version to make it work on Stack Overflow, but everything is good now. Only thing I don't like is it tends to make the page loads laggier, and elements jump around after load, which makes them moving targets for the mouse. But that's really unavoidable with a userscript and not really your fault. It's nice work overall.

Comment: SOX seems non-functional now that the new top-bar has been rolled out

Comment: @Valorum thanks, I am aware of this, I just haven't gotten round to fixing it yet! :/ I'll try my best to fix it over the weekend :). The Dev version has been fixed for Stack Overflow and the main Meta which you can install so you can configure the settings if you go to those sites! Sorry it's not fixed yet :(

Comment: @Valorum many many months later, if you're still interested, I managed to fix it... sorry for how long this took

Comment: Is this compatible with SOUP?

Comment: @sag It should be! Some people in the past have told me about issues when both are installed but I try my best to fix them :) If you use SOX with SOUP and notice something off, please do tell me!

Comment: I get `404 - Not Found at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soscripted/sox/v2.2.0/sox.enhanced_editor.js` on FF. How can I fix it?

Comment: @phuclv Please install the [development version](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js) where this should be fixed! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It seems the problem is due to Greasemonkey. I replaced it with Tampermonkey and now it's working fine. Probably that was the reason many of my scripts didn't work in FF. But I don't know why it asks `To complete the SOX installation, you need to get an access token! Please press "OK" to continue and follow the instructions in the window that opens.` every time I open a new page

Comment: @phuclv Do you have a popup blocked when you click 'OK'? does the access token screen come up (where it says 'thanks, you can close this window...')?

Comment: I didn't see any popup blocked message appeared. But I managed to get the token by clicking the gears button and click the key at the bottom

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, Thanks for finding the time to get back into this (and thanks to others who have worked on it)!  Once you use SOX, it's hard to be without it.  I've stuck with FF 52 ESR because I rely on some old add-ons that don't have replacements, and I'm running Tampermonkey.  I've encountered some bugs, but they could well be FF-related, so I won't even bother reporting them unless I replicate them in a current FF.  The current version looks great, BTW.

Comment: Did this one just stopped working on Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)? I'm with tampermonkey v4.8.41.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It seems to still be working in that chrome version. Could you try [the latest dev version](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js) and see if that works? If not, what part is not working? Do you have any errors in the browser console (access it with F12)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Sorry for the delayed response: It now works. I do not know what the problem was, but after a restart of my laptop, things are back to normal. I'll chime in again if the issue is reproduced. Meanwhile, thanks for the great tool and Cheers!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh no worries! please do let me know if it happens again! :)

Comment: Can anyone help me figure out why this works on one computer (Windows 7 Waterfox, Tampermonkey) but not on another (Windows 10 Waterfox or Firefox, Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey).  It's been like this for years and I've never been able to figure out what's missing.  Tampermonkey is enabled, SOX is turned on, there's a gear icon at the top bar, with everything enabled, but nothing actually changes.

Comment: @endolith really sorry for the late reply - do you mind dropping in the gitter chat and we can try figuring this out? :) https://gitter.im/soscripted/sox

Comment: The gear (settings) button seems to be missing currently (dev version). Was there some sort of layout change that made gear button disappear? Tested on Chrome & Violentmonkey and Firefox & Tampermonkey.

Comment: @galacticninja Thanks for your comment, I just fixed this in the [the latest dev version (2.7.12)](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js)! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Thanks. That fixed the issue. Gear button is now back. However, there seems to be another issue. The mod diamond in the topbar that has notifications of new questions on a site's meta is now missing. Happens in both Chrome & Violentmonkey, and Firefox & Tampermonkey.

Comment: @galacticninja Ah the change in SE must have broken all the features that use the topbar :/ would you be able to open an issue on GitHub so I can track this and other bugs more easily? I'll work on a fix ASAP!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Change Log

On 2016-02-12, SOOF was renamed to SOX and rewritten by ᔕᖺᘎᕊ and ᴉʞuǝ. The versioning was reset.

- 2022-05-18 - [v2.8.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.8.0+is%3Aclosed)

  - Fix bugs in various features due to SE layout changes
  - Add feature to add answer count to question header
  - Behind-the-scenes performance improvements (e.g., reduce usage of jQuery for efficiency - thanks @double-beep!)
  - Deprecate "align badges by their class on user profile pages" feature (now natively implemented!)
  - Deprecate "differentiate spoilers from empty blockquotes" (now native!)
- 2020-10-19 - [v2.7.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.7.0+is%3Aclosed)

  - Fix bugs in various features (thanks @double-beep for many of these!)
  - Add feature to copy markdown for comments
  - Add feature to add scrolling to room list in usercards in chat
  - Only run SOX on HTTPS
  - Deprecate "add timeline button" feature (now natively implemented!
  - Deprecate "show question state in suggested edit review queue" (now native!)
- 2019-09-07 - [v2.6.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.6.0+is%3Aclosed)

  - Fix bugs in various features
  - Add support for StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark theme
  - Remove dependency on Font Awesome for icons (use SVG sprites instead)
  - Update many features to work with recent SE HTML markup/CSS changes (thanks to [@double-beep](https://stackexchange.com/users/14688437/double-beep) for many of these fixes!)
  - Add feature to open imgur image in a modal on click
- 2019-06-04 - [v2.5.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.5.0+is%3Aclosed)

  - Only inject into Github issues if you are on the SOX repo
  - Fix bugs in various features
  - Deprecate the 'hide HNQ' feauter (now implemented natively)
  - Improve SOX's performance with many behind-the-scenes changes:

    - Reduce jQuery usage
    - Reduce number of API requests by caching them for a short period
    - Improve SOX's use of MutationObservers by specifying specific
      targets to observe in all uses
  - Improve SOX's Github Community Profile
  - Remove EOL RawGit dependency
- 2019-02-03 - [v2.4.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.4.0+is%3Aclosed):

  - Introduced 'feature packs' -- easily find and enable features that have been categorised into groups such as 'Major UI Tweaks' and 'Power User Features'
  - You no longer **have** to have an access token to use SOX; if you choose not to, then any features needing the API will simply be disabled. Thanks @Izzy for the suggestion.
  - Deprecated feature to paste images directly into the post editor (now native); feature to add notifications to your inbox when a post you downvoted was edited.
  - Added feature to hide the 'how to ask/format/tag' boxes that show when asking new questions
  - Added feature to add a link to the tag wiki page on the new tag popup boxes
  - Added feature to replace 'help' in the site-switcher to a link to the /on-topic
    page of the site
  - Added feature to add custom magic links to both posts and comments
  - Various bug fixes
- 2018-09-02 - [v2.3.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.3.0+is%3Aclosed):

  - Greasemonkey is no longer supported. Please use Tampermonkey
  - You can now import and export your settings from the SOX dialog
  - Added feature to paste images directly into SE textareas without using the image dialog
  - The old topbar is no longer supported (affects Area 51 mainly)
  - The feature that lets you watch posts for edits will soon be available as a separate userscript, and has been removed from SOX
  - Behind the scenes refactoring by @GaurangTandon
  - The fixed topbar feature has been deprecated as it is natively supported now!
  - Added feature to only show comment flagging/upvote buttons on hover (like it used to be)
  - Added feature to add the tag wiki link on the new tag popup box
  - Various bug fixes
- 2018-06-15 - [v2.2.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A2.2.0+is%3Aclosed):

  - lots of bug fixes (see milestone link above)
  - fixes major issue where SOX settings cog didn't show up
  - works on FF again
  - deprecated a few features
  - added a few features (`disableVoteButtons`, `addTimelineAndRevisionLinks`)
- 2018-02-24 - [v2.1.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20milestone%3Av2.1.0%20):

  - various bug fixes
  - many new features added
  - updated to be compatible with the new topbar and site design changes made by SE
  - versioning changed to MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH style
- 2016-12-21 - [v2.0.2](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20milestone%3Av2.0.2%20):

  - revamped dialog to include info hover buttons
  - added `disableOwnPostVoteButtons`, `flagPercentageBar`, `replyToOwnChatMessages` (thanks @IStoleThePies), `hideCertainQuestions`, `inlineEditorEverywhere` (thanks @nicael) features
  - fixed `enhancedEditor` feature
  - fixed `downvotedPostsEditAlert` feature
  - fixed issues with certain features not working in Firefox
  - deprecated `addEllipsis` feature
  - reordered features in dialog and made more categories for easier searching
  - added debug mode to help SOX devs fix bugs quicker and easier
  - features no longer run on page where they weren't designed to run on, fixing lots of weird bugs
  - completely rewritten `fixedTopbar` feature to work on all sites without manual configuration (thanks @IStoleThePies!)
  - fixed design issues with features with their own dialogs (thanks @IStoleThePies!)
  - fixed long-standing bug where the fancy vote buttons caused tearing on Skeptics.SE (thanks @IStoleThePies!)
  - fixes bugs in various features, which can be seen in the v2.0.2 Github milestone
- 2016-10-01 - [v2.0.1](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20milestone%3Av2.0.1%20):

  - many more bug fixes
  - fixed major issue where script did not work at all on Firefox
  - fixed cross-browser compatibility issues with the access token
  - rewritten downvotedPostsEditAlert feature to make it easier to use and more functional
  - known bug: the downvotedPostsEditAlert feature is flaky right now
- 2016-07-02 - [v2.0.0](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aclosed+milestone%3Av2.0.0):

  - Completely refactored version fixing a lot of bugs
  - deprecated feature that hides the search bar, feature that removes excessive exclamation marks from comments, quickCommentShortcuts feature
  - removed Ace Editor from the enhanced editor feature
  - bug fixes
  - fixed timing issues
  - setting dialog UI updates
  - script now request oauth access after installing to prevent rate limiting on certain features
  - added alignBadgesByClass, quickAuthorInfo, warnNotLoggedIn, hotNetworkQuestionsFiltering, hiddenCommentsIndicator features
- 2016-04-05 - [v1.0.3](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+milestone%3Av1.0.3):

  - SOX settings dialog now has a search bar and is a menu just like the inbox
  - new features
  - bug fixes
- 2016-03-06 - v1.0.2:

  - rewrote parts of script to allow better control over what features run when
  - bug fixes
  - added new feature (enhanced editor)
- 2016-02-28 - v1.0.1:

  - lots of bug fixes
  - rewrote some helper functions
  - built in error handling
- 2016-02-12 - v1.0: SOOF is now SOX.

Please see the revision history for this post to see the change log for SOOF, before it was renamed.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) 
I had some trouble getting your script to run on Firefox / Greasemonkey.  It turns out that I needed to replace this line:

```js
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js
```

with:

```js
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js
```

With this change, the script seems to work on Firefox (although I haven't properly tested all the features yet).

---

I also noticed a few issues with the options pop-up:

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The pop-up appears in a weird location, partially off the screen.  I managed to fix this issue by changing the `style` attribute from the original

  ```css
  display:inline-block; position:fixed; margin:auto; top:50%;
  margin:-100px 0 0 -150px; z-index:2; background-color:gray;
  color:white; -webkit-border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  ```

  to:

  ```css
  display:inline-block; position:fixed; top:10px; left:50%; width:500px;
  margin-left:-250px; z-index:2; background-color:gray; color:white;
  padding: 10px; border-radius: 15px;
  ```
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Having the checkboxes at the end of the option descriptions is somewhat ugly awkward; they'd look nicer and be easier to click if they were at the beginning.  You could also simplify the HTML by nesting the checkboxes inside their labels, as in:

  ```html
  <label><input type=checkbox id=id checked> Text </label><br>
  ```
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Every time I open the options dialog, all the checkboxes get checked.  It would be much better to have them retain their previous state.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Closing the options dialog using the "Close" link (instead of the "Submit" button) resets all the features to active, due to this line:

  ```js
  GM_deleteValue('featureOptions'); //Delete the setting when clicked
  ```

  In particular, this interferes with trying to make the checkboxes retain their state (which is otherwise fairly simple).  Simply removing this (apparently unnecessary) line makes it work better; the new settings will override the old when submitted, anyway.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I don't see any particular reason why I *shouldn't* be allowed to disable all the features, if I want.  That extra check seems just plain useless to me.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Also, the "Options were saved!" alert after editing the options gets kind of annoying after a while.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) 
Also, the "add features" link injection doesn't seem to work on the fancy new user profile currently in testing on [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com). You might want to add compatibility for that, especially since it'll likely be rolled out network-wide sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the incompatibility with Firefox, will look into that. I don't know why the options box comes off-screen, works for me, so I'll try using your CSS on different resolutions - that may be the problem...? I'll make the text come after the checkbox (I'm not the best in design and user interaction ;p). I'll make it so that the checkboxes fill from the settings. **But** could you clarify the last bullet please? I don't exactly get what you say - are you saying there should be an option to disable all the features? And I'll see what I can do about the MSE profile change.

Comment: I just meant that the code that checks if all the checkboxes are unchecked, and, if so, brings up an alert saying "Please check at least one box!", seems to be completely unnecessary (and mildly annoying when testing).

Comment: Ps. [I forked your gist](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/3aa3e9239ae42e01d57b) and committed fixes for some of the issues listed above. I don't think I can create a proper pull request for a gist, but you may want to review the [changes](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/3aa3e9239ae42e01d57b/revisions) and merge them yourself, if they look good to you.

Comment: Whoops...! Only just saw your message! I just published the gist and looks like they're the same changes- sorry! Regarding your last edit-isn't that being a bit too pedantic? I think it's unnecessary-I agree it can be a pain in testing, but can be useful when being used normally - or you might just think nothing happened without checking the console, and I don't think you should need to do that. Your CSS works in different resolutions, so I've used that - thanks again for that - and I'm still in the process of checking with Firefox incompatibilities. Please accept my edit for the status-* tags

Comment: Sure, accepted. I can live with the alert, but I don't really see why it's necessary; the dialog closing already indicates that something happened, and generally when you click a "Save" button (BTW, shouldn't it say something like "Save settings" instead of "Submit"?), you'd assume it saved the settings. With the new persistent checkboxes, it's also easy enough to verify if you don't trust it.

Comment: You put a good argument forward ;p I guess... you're right... I'll remove the alert and rename the button in the next version (when I've tested on Firefox and also add the needed `require`) :)

Comment: Thanks, no problem. :) Ps. I notice that there's already some overlap (e.g. [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129593)) between your script and SOUP, and I think I might want to steal a few more of the less controversial features (with appropriate credit, of course!). ;) That said, I think your script will make an excellent complement to SOUP (which *doesn't* come with a settings panel to toggle features, and so generally avoids anything controversial). You may have noticed that I've added a link to your script from the [SOUP home page](http://stackapps.com/q/4486). :)

Comment: Thanks for adding this link to SOUP :) I have no problem with you stealing some things - I think the many difference between SOUP and this is that SOUP generally fixes *bugs* while this (no acronym unfortunately ;( - AOF?) adds *features* - so a slight overlap is obviously going to happen (eg. a bug, but not actually a bug = bug+feature-request), but a full on replica is just useless ;p. And I have no problem with you stealing snippets for SOUP :)

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm using v1.4 and I noticed that the following features seem to clash somehow:

- Make the topbar fixed (stay at the top as you scroll)
- Make the vote buttons sticky

The topbar stays at the top, that works fine, but when scrolling, the upvote button disappears under the topbar. See the following screenshot for an example:

[image: screenshot]

It would be great if the upvote button was visible all the time.

Comment: I'll look at this and your other bug report and push 1.5 out by this weekend hopefully :) +1 for both :)

Comment: This issue is now solved (at least on developer branch) ;)

Answer (score 3):

v1.5 DEV has a problem with the "Extra Mod Diamond" added to the toolbar when used in combination with [stackoverflow-code-expando](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/111973)

When [stackoverflow-code-expando](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/111973) is disabled there is no issue.

Appears to be a z-ordering issue?

Firefox 38.0.5, Windows 7 4Bit.

Here is a screenshot of the problem from StackOverflow.

[image]

Comment: yeah - it's probs z-index. It's the weekend now(!) - so I'll update the script with a fix to this (and the freehand circles css bug!) :)

Comment: I've pushed an update to the develop branch - can you update and check if it's fixed please?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Hmm. Strange. New version was installed yesterday (white diamond) but today a) doesn't appear to be running (no diamond at all) and b) no "add features" visible on profile pages :(. I've disabled all other scripts and reinstalled, restarted firefox, but no change ...

Comment: Anything in console...?

Comment: Timestamp: 28/06/2015 09:44:50
Error: The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading.
Source File: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=8ac5fbfa1bd9
Line: 1

Comment: Timestamp: 28/06/2015 09:44:52
Error: jQuery is not defined
Source File: file:///C:/Users/DavidPostill/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/5ubcfk8m.default/gm_scripts/SE_Additional_Optional_Features/jquery-ui.min.js
Line: 5

Comment: Timestamp: 28/06/2015 09:45:34
Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
Source File: chrome://web-developer/content/overlay/javascript/overlay.js
Line: 7333

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25283/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-).

Comment: Whoops! Can you please try installing v1.5? I pushed it yesterday to the main branch - it fixed someone else's problem on Firefox - it should fix yours as well!

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please can you raise an issue at Github? It's much easier to manage over there!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ No change to the stackoverflow-code-expando issue :/. The good news is the diamond and "add features" is back ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill As far as I see the z-index is not really needed. So a simple `$(".prettyprinted").css("z-index",0)` should solve the problem. (At least it does for me)

Answer (score 3):

## This doesn't work for Stack Overflow, due to the new topbar design.

Workaround:

For now, you must use the Dev version to make it work on SO.

Comment: This has been fixed in the Dev version, please could you install that and it try it? :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I will, thanks for informing me. Keeping this here. EDIT: Did it,  and it's good. I'm not sure how to keep both versions though...

Comment: You can delete the original version :) you only need to keep one version, and the Dev is newer than the other one so you can just delete that one :)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (thanks to ArtOfCode, that is :)

This appears to break the styling of title bars on at least beta SE sites. It would be good if it didn't obscure the top part of the title bar.

To see what I mean:

Without 'Fix topbar position' enabled:

[image]

With it enabled:

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24206/discussion-between-artofcode-and-).

Answer (score 2):

SOX 2.8.0 and 2.8.3DEV both fail to load under Chrome on SE sites where you are not a member.
I don't know if this is intentional or not, but it seems like it should work regardless.

The settings icon does not appear in the top-bar, none of the SOX features function, and the console reports:

> *chrome-extension://dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/userscript.html?name=Stack%2520Overflow%2520Extras%2520(SOX).user.js&id=9cf7e741-6827-41a6-b33e-da00a230471b:3*
>
> Uncaught SOX: There was an error while attempting to initialize the SOX Settings Dialog, please report this on GitHub.
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')

The error itself appears to come from line 3 of https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js - the current version of this is 1.13.2 but switching to that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report! I'll look into this as soon as I can!

Comment: I just pushed a fixed version in [dev 2.8.4](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js)!

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The `Change the 'share' link to show link as markdown format` feature has the annoying side-effect that the replaced text in the form `[text](link)` is not selected when clicking the share link.

It is pretty annoying to manually having to select the text - it would be better if the whole text was already selected, so I could copy it directly from the box.

Comment: [fixed in 1.5 dev](https://github.com/shu8/SE_OptionalFeatures/issues/4) :)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Fixed in [this](https://github.com/shu8/SE_OptionalFeatures/blob/develop/features.user.js#L117-L202) build

This is really borked on askubuntu:

[image]

1. The bar position is broken.
2. The vote button is  broken.
3. The post content moves to the left.

Comment: I presume this is with fixed topbar? You've just managed to get 2 of the bugs related to the fixed topbar happen at one time: `The vote button is broken`: https://github.com/shu8/SE_OptionalFeatures/issues/5. `The post content moves to the left`: That happens at random times - it's a glitch, but I've never been able to properly repro it! So I can't fix it... however a scroll up and down fixes it.

Comment: However, the `bar position is broken` is new - I've never used Ask Ubuntu before so I didn't notice it. But sorry - I'm not going to change this because it only affects Ask Ubuntu :/ BTW Please can you post any issues or feature requests on github now? Thanks! :)

Comment: The fixed topbar has a lot of issues with it... I might just get rid of it... I'm not too sure yet - I'll think about it!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ [Here you go!](https://github.com/shu8/SE_OptionalFeatures/issues/11)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

'Get access token?' link broken, generates the following error:

> VM2649:3464 Uncaught channelUrl must be under the current domain
>   r @ VM2649:3464
>   (anonymous function) @ VM2649:3740
>   n.event.dispatch @ VM2649:8
>   r.handle @ VM2649:8

Running on chrome, Version 49.0.2623.110 m

Works only when clicking it on `http://meta.stackexchange.com/` - If this is intended, maybe show a warning or only display the link when on meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry! I completely forgot about the meta SE URL I gave.. I'll fix this ASAP. If you could post this [on GitHub](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues), I can ping you over there when it gets fixed :) Thanks for the bug report!

Comment: No worries :) - Bug report is here: https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/50

Answer (score 1):

## Installation completion dialog box opens every time I visit a SE page.

Solution:

1. Open browser console.
2. Click on the first URL to get your SE access token.
3. Approve the extension.

After that, the popup will reopen, you just need to save your preferred settings again.

Comment: A popup should have opened. Check you haven't got a pop-up blocker blocking it. And would it be possible to put these in 1 answer please? (Or delete the first one! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The thing is that I have already done the thing. Yes the pop-up did open the first time, after that the popup doesn't open but the dialog box still shows up. I don't think the dialog box or the popup should show up after installation has been completed. And no, it's not possible, since they are entirely different issues.

Comment: Can you make sure you only have 1 version installed, and if it still happens, click reset at the bottom of the dialog and refresh the page. If it still happens, please open the console and post the contents here. We prefer to use github for reporting bugs because it makes it more manageable, that's the only reason I asked to delete or merge them, but it's fine

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes it seems I only have 2.0.22 (Dev). I will try what you recommend and see if it works.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The console had a URL which I clicked, approved and got an access token. Problem seems to be solved now, although I'd like something like local memory. EDIT: When I tried to edit this post to include a solution, the popup suddenly appeared. I just had to re-save to solve this time.

Answer (score 1):

My SOX appears to "time-out" after 24 hours. Some features are still available, but elements like ***'Show tags for the question an answer belongs to on search pages (for better context)'*** stop working.

Entering the console shows this link

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   '[Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox)' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://stackapps.com/posts/6091/revisions'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

And clicking the link goes to

> {"error_id":403,"error_message":"`key` is not valid for passed
>   `access_token`, token not found.","error_name":"access_denied"}

---

- This issue can be resolved by resetting SOX and requesting a new token.

Comment: Hi, could you try installing the development version: https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js and see if the problem still occurs? :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - I've noticed that the link you get when you open the console says "http://soscripted.github.io/sox/#access_token=ts67upOKAiRKFZgf*xFSqQ))&expires=86399". Presumably that's in seconds, hence why it times out after a day.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - I don't know how to do that. I'm reliant on clicking the "install" button. The link you sent me to doesn't appear to have one of those

Comment: When I click update, then open the console it say "*ados.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
(unknown) SOX:  Deleting feature "Unsorted-parseCrossSiteLinks" (category rename?)*

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ -Ah, now that's new. There's a key-shaped icon that says "request new access token". When I click it, it takes me to a page that asks for "perpetual access", then takes me to another page that gives me a key and there's no "expires=" in the URL.

Comment: Great! Looks like it *should* work now! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - That worked just fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

The recent top bar rollout seems to have broken the tools again as I am no longer able to access the menus such as settings or the meta link which shows new activity and my name is now showing as false.

This is using the dev version

Comment: Hi, I am aware of this, but I haven't gotten round to fixing it yet :( sorry, I'll try getting it fixed asap

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but if you're still interested in using this script, I've fixed it for chrome in the latest version and am working on a FF fix too!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Thanks for the update, just installed your latest version and looking forward to using it again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 2.8.3 DEV with Tampermonkey on Firefox.

The primary feature I sought was the:

> Show the flag outcome time when viewing your Flag History

It works. However, it is still somewhat difficult to find recent changes. Would it be possible to sort the flagging based on outcome time?

For example having this list sorted with the outcome from 4 hours ago first, the 11 hour second and the 13 hour last?

[image: list]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! This definitely seems possible and useful. I'm a bit busy right now and I'm not sure if that page is paginated at the moment (if so, it might complicate implementing sorting for all pages), but would you be able to repost this as a feature request issue on GitHub? It's much easier to track that way (and will make sure I don't forget to look into this properly)! :)