# Inline editor regardless of reputation

Tags: script, editing

The following simple script provides an ability to edit any posts inline regardless of reputation (works if logged out also).

[**Download / view code**](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8587-always-edit-inline/code)

Screenshot from there:

[image]

Comment: @Jon What? The code doesn't work as it is shown on my screenshot? For me, this script works perfectly. I installed it on Tamper monkey.

Comment: its working now, although its a bit small and i can't read it

Comment: (beating the double-gif record - now it will be triple gif)

Comment: isn't this cheating?

Comment: @Jon what is :D

Comment: @Jon (actually, I wasn't going to ping you - but at this time you can see that there're four questions!)

Comment: @nicael do you mind if I add this to [SOX](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088)? (with credit of course! ;) It's a pretty handy feature and we were thinking of adding it

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Feel free to do that :)

Comment: @nicael great! I will add it in the next version! :D BTW, long time no see on Meta.. have you found a massive bug or something!? :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ waaa, did you know [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over)?? What a prediction

Comment: @nicael so... a few months later... it's been added in [v2.0.2 dev AP](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js)! :) Sorry it took sooooo long, I just had a massive to-do list! :/ and thanks for letting us add it in SOX! :D