# Script Request - Meta Notifications

Tags: support, app-request, script-request

Mods are notified when a new meta post is started on HSM meta by a diamond on the top bar lighting up in blue. Here it is, not lit up:

[image]

**Proposal**: Let users of sufficiently high rep see the same notifications as moderators. This would be quite handy for those active on meta.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256318/can-high-rep-users-be-allowed-to-see-meta-notifications)

> (1) How does the diamond know when to turn back off?
>
> (2) I assume this is only active on given main sites, like site-X, and only indicates for meta-X? That is, it is not universal, meaning, you do not see meta-X alerts while on, say, Stack Apps.
>
> (3) Would this not get annoying if every SE site did this?

1. After you visit the meta site.
2. Yes. You also wouldn't see Meta.SE alerts anywhere (maybe SE homepage?). Only the `meta.site.se` would be shows on `site.se`
3. Only lighting up - not a big thing.

---

Can a userscript / extension be created that would do this? I'm not sure if there is an API / reliable method for detecting posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a userscript to do this.

### Update: This has been added to the dev version of [my SE Additional Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) - please install that instead of this. Any updates will go straight to that userscript, not this!

---

Get it at [Github](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/newMetaQuestionModAlert.user.js).

It gets the latest 5 questions posted on the per-site meta of the current site and adds a diamond to the topbar.

It is red if there are new questions, and white if there aren't.

It decides whether you've seen the questions by saving the latest question via `GM_setValue` - if the latest question via the API is equal to that, it will show white. So, basically once you click the button, it will go white the next time.

[image]

[image]

Note: I have no experience with the standard mod diamond so sorry if it doesn't look right!

On sites without a meta, it will always look like the bottom gif above.

V1.1:

- added support for multiple sites (I forgot about the possibility of using multiple sites last time!)
- made it so the box closes if you click outside it
- made it work in firefox (thanks @Brock :)

v1.2:

- genuine colours (thanks [@Doorknob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200301/allow-me-to-get-notifications-for-new-meta-posts-like-mods-do/#comment838612_257092))

Comment: Neat :) I've customised it to be light grey, then medium blue. And be a smaller, squarer diamond: ◆ Thanks for this :)

Comment: Did you test this script on Firefox+Greasemonkey?  It should not work!  It uses jQuery without `@require`ing it, while the sandbox is on.  ... I see that kind of thing works on Tampermonkey now (it shouldn't), which may be a security hole that was introduced in TM in the last few months.

Comment: @BrockAdams I've edited the script to `require` jQuery. I've tested it and it works now in Firefox :)

Comment: Good!  Now help me test/document Tampermonkey for this new potential security flaw (You break it, you bought it). :P