# OBSOLETE - See the SOX post -- Side By Side Editing

Tags: script, obsolete, editing

> ### This script no longer works and is no longer supported.  See [the *Stack Overflow Extras* (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) for this functionality.

### Screenshot

[image: editor on the left, preview on the right]

### About

This userscript adds a button to the editor toolbar ('Toggle Side-By-Side Editing') so you can view the preview and markdown side by side when asking or answering a question or when editing an existing question or answer.

### Installation

After installing Greasemonkey in Firefox or Tampermonkey in Chrome, click **[here](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/side-by-side-editing.user.js)**.

### Authors

This userscript was originally adapted from [a bookmarklet by ˈjuː.zɚ79365](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9841/) by [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ](https://stackapps.com/users/26088/). Since then [Antonio Vargas](https://stackapps.com/users/36263/) has made some contributions to it as well.

### Code

Almost all of the reformatting is done using CSS with jQuery's toggleClass().

For more detail check out the <kbd>[source code](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/blob/master/side-by-side-editing.user.js)</kbd> on GitHub.

---

Please post bugs/feature-requests as answers over here. I'll try my best to fix/add them!

Comment: I loaded this on one computer a few months ago and it's great.  I tried to load it on another computer several times over the last few days and get a 404 error from the download link.

Comment: @fixer1234 weird.. it's still there! You can install [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) instead, which contains this feature as well as a bunch of other features! It's also been updated since I posted this, so should be less buggy! :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.  BTW, the problem might be a dependency or incorrect link.  The actual error message is "Error downloading URL: https://gist/github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js"

Comment: @fixer1234 ah yes, I see the problem. I've updated the script. Could you try reinstalling that? (btw I've replied to that comment on GH! Thanks for trying it and sorry for the problems you have! I'll try my best to get them sorted!)

Comment: SOX is quite a work of art.  I'm not sure it has enough features though.  :-)  Any chance the two side-by-side editing issues are related?  Any potential conflict or interaction between this standalone script and the side-by-side feature of SOX?

Comment: I retested this script on the same installation as SOX.  At first, I thought it wasn't working, but it worked on two questions, and one out of two answers.  This is the answer it didn't work on if it helps: [Windows default font in bars? [duplicate]](http://superuser.com/a/1069262/364367).  (Didn't work = no "button" for side-by-side editing).

Comment: Hi @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, this script: no longer seems to work and hasn't been updated in a few years.  Plus you seem to be steering people to *SOX*.  **Should we mark this post as obsolete** or do you intend to update the script shortly?

Comment: @Brock you're right -- I can mark it as obsolete or mark it as a dupe of SOX, which do you think it better? :)

Comment: I'm leaning towards the latter because of [this](https://stackapps.com/a/8113) and I know how annoying it is to arrive at a promising page and be told that the princess is in another castle...  If you really want it closed as a dupe instead, roll back the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the description to reflect the new version of the userscript.

### New features in 1.1

- Side by side editing can be used when editing existing questions or answers.
- Can be toggled on and off by clicking the new button again.
- When turned on the editor is stretched to the current length of the preview.

Comment: Bug: this doesn't work when I am editing posts. It only works when I am posting new posts.

Comment: @caveman that's been fixed in [SOX](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088), which contains this feature and many others :)

Comment: Its still not working (unable to edit existing post with this option on)